# Monitor tcp data

Tags: c#, c++, windows, tcp, monitor

I need to monitor the packets transferred to a ip address via a tcp connection. At the same time I need to monitor the packets transferred from the same ip.

Currently I am using [smsniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) to do this

How to do this in C++ or C# in windows.

Comment: Just found some Project's : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CSNetworkSniffer.aspx , http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/pacanal.aspx , http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharppcap.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Libpcap can do this. It has both C++ and C# bindings.